# Unable to get the second Parent of my Input element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup inside my web application , where there is an input element, now i want to change the text of the below span from "-" to something else.

Now here is the markup :-

```
<span dir="none">
    <table id="OrderQuickOrder_a91a0ce2-7fb6-4c9c-97f5-e851cf4f10a6_MultiChoiceTable" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
            <span class="ms-RadioText" title="Yes">
            <input id="OrderQuickOrder_****_MultiChoiceOption_0" type="checkbox">
            <label for="OrderQuickOrder_**_MultiChoiceOption_0">Yes</label>
            </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</span>
<span class="ms-metadata">-</span>
```

and this is my jQuery selector:-

```
$('input[id^="OrderQuickOrder_"]').parent('span').parent('span').nextAll('span').after('<a id="dialogtrigger" href="/*****" target="_blank">Items Order</a>' );
```

but the above code did not change anything. i think the `.parent('span').parent('span')` is not able to select the parent span of the direct parent span of the input element...

Comment: Please never post pictures of your code. Post the actual code.

Comment: Yes, it makes it easier for us to reuse the code if its available rather than having to retype all the code to debug it

Comment: @ScottMarcus ok done.. i provided the actual markup

Comment: @Keith i provided the actual markup code..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use parents() to get to your selection:

https://jsfiddle.net/fLb89q4p/

```
$('input[id^="OrderQuickOrder_"]').parents()
     .nextAll('span')
     .after('<a id="dialogtrigger" href="/*****" target="_blank">Items Eligable for Quick Order</a>' );
```

If you want to remove the text and insert new text use:

```
$('input[id^="OrderQuickOrder_"]').parents()
     .nextAll('span')
     .text('')
     .after('<a id="dialogtrigger" href="/*****" target="_blank">Items Eligable for Quick Order</a>' );
```